# inheriting classes from python modules - sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, oop

For a tkinter GUI with an sqlite3 database, in order to create the interface part of your class you would inherit from tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk
class MyApp(tk.tk):
    def __init__(self):        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
```

But how do you handle sqlite3 within MyApp?

I've looked at https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html.

For instance, in order to connect to the database, should I inherit the Connection class?

I want to be able to create/connect to the database, insert data, update data, view all data, and close the database.

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

The comment feature won't let me comment on what juanpa.arrivillaga said, so I'm doing it as an edit.

I'm completely new to OOP. I don't understand why I wouldn't need to inherit if I want to create an sqlite3 database within my class, when I do need to inherit to create a window (tkinter frame). What's the difference? Thanks

Comment: Why would you inherit?

Comment: You would inherit a class when it provides some functionality (e.g. it *is a window*) and you want to customise some aspects of it or "fill in some blanks" that the base class does not provide. That's not typically necessary for an SQL interface, you just use the existing class, instantiate it and call its methods.

Comment: Also, inheritance is not strictly necessary to build tkinter GUI's, They are just a tree of widgets in a root `Tk()` window that respond to, or propagate events. But it is a common used style for convenience, and most GUI's are (an benefit from being) object oriented anyway.